# How can I see the domain name or ip of the PC accessing my API method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

I have an API method deploy on my local server,

```
@app.post("/test/api")
async def method():
     if incoming.request.url or domain == "this":
         do some operation
     else:
         skip it
     .....
     return something
```

Now, Few people are using my API method, but is there any way I could track who is calling my api method and do specific extra operations to the once I specified who is calling my api.

How can I track the incoming domain name or ip or url of the people who are using my api method?

Note: Need a basic example on how to acheive it if you familiar with it

Is it something possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using flask it could happen simply by getting `remote_addr` as below:

```
from flask import FLASK, request
@app.route('/test/api', methods=['POST']):
def method():
    visitor_ip = request.remote_addr
```

In fastapi it should happen like this: `request.client.host`

any way you can work with **headers** in your code and get many details of your client

Answer (score 0):

If you can access incoming request headers, then check if [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) has IP address of client. If not it is possible that changing configuration of your setup will make it works as intended, however I have not experience with neither `fastapi` or `uvicorn`, so I am unable to write anything more precise.